# How can I change the Icon of a Shortcut on my Home Screen?

Tags: customization, home-screen-shortcuts

I have a couple direct dial to landline shortcuts that I use at work regularly.  There are no avatars associated with those contacts and the Homescreen icon just shows a generic Android Avatar so they are indistinguishable.  I have a couple other contacts whose avatars are still indistinguishable because they are so small.  I'd like to be able to set a shortcut icon instead of having to mess with making custom avatars.  Any apps to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Desktop Visualizer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/jp.co.bii.android.app.dskvzr) does the trick (and a little bit more)