# How to change dashboard icons?

Tags: htc-legend, home-screen-shortcuts

I want to be able to change the dashbord icons/text on my Android.

I've got HTC sense on the phone, but I'm currently running ADW.Launcher.

I know there's another launcher widget that allows photos as icons, but I'd like something so I can get the sleakness of the iOS icons e.g. http://dribbble.com/shots/57799

Comment: I asked this last week: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/366/how-can-i-change-the-icon-of-a-shortcut-on-my-home-screen

Answer (score 1):

[Desktop Visualizer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/jp.co.bii.android.app.dskvzr)

[image: http://www.appbrain.com/app/jp.co.bii.android.app.dskvzr]

It's the best I could come up with.